# How to restrict mobile view in my web application in Zurb foundation?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, mobile, zurb-foundation

We have developed web application using ASP .net MVC. Our application used ZURB foundation. Using zurb foundation we are able to view application layout according to device on which it run like desktop, tablet and mobile. Our requirement is to show tablet view in mobiles.

We need to show tablet view as our mobile view, how can we do?

We do not want to show zurb's default view for mobile, how can we restrict mobile view and show tablet view at mobile view?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try to reassign the default values:

```
$small-range: (0em, 0em);
$medium-range: (0.063em, 64em);
```